# Theme the Storybook sidebar icons

Tags: storybook

I was wondering if there is a way to theme the Storybook sidebar icons?. See screenshot below

I was able to [theme Storybook](https://storybook.js.org/docs/configurations/theming/) but unfortunately I couldn't find a way to theme the sidebar icons.

Thanks,
Kavin Mehta.

[image: Sidebar Icons]

Comment: Did you find a way to change those icons?

Comment: No unfortunately not.

Comment: Actually, I found a tricky way to change those icons :)) I'll post an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat hacky, but it worked for me. All you need to do is use Javascript to update the icons in the `DOMContentLoaded` event callback. Add this code snippet to the end of the `.storybook/manager-head.html` file and re-run your storybook to see the results.

```js
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    let bookmarkHollowIcon = document.getElementById(
      "icon--bookmarkhollow"
    ).firstChild;
    bookmarkHollowIcon.setAttribute(
      "d",
      "M 943.548 481.063 C 950.438 497.039 954 514.416 954 532.001 C 954 549.586 950.438 566.962 943.548 582.939 C 936.665 598.915 926.615 613.113 914.108 624.557 L 631.498 883.042 C 621.145 892.507 607.959 897.714 594.323 897.714 L 127.121 897.714 C 111.971 897.714 97.443 891.292 86.731 879.86 C 76.018 868.428 70 852.929 70 836.764 L 70 227.238 C 70 211.073 76.018 195.57 86.731 184.139 C 97.443 172.708 111.971 166.286 127.121 166.286 L 594.323 166.286 C 607.959 166.287 621.145 171.491 631.498 180.96 L 914.108 439.445 C 926.615 450.89 936.665 465.086 943.548 481.063 Z M 822.288 567.27 C 826.554 563.364 830.277 558.245 832.926 552.098 C 835.573 545.945 837.017 539.075 837.017 532.001 C 837.017 524.927 835.573 518.056 832.926 511.904 C 830.277 505.756 826.554 500.638 822.288 496.732 L 568.454 264.567 L 166.984 264.567 L 166.984 799.434 L 568.454 799.434 L 822.288 567.27 Z"
    );
    bookmarkHollowIcon.setAttribute("fill-rule", "evenodd");
  });
```

I replaced the `d` attribute of the SVG icon with my desired icon. Here is the result:

[image: how to change storybook default icon]

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me. Remove fill for svg icons and fill it based on theme. And then add a decorator to the desired story (https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/writing-stories/decorators).
Something like that

```
export const Dark = Template.bind({});

    Dark.args = {};
    Dark.decorators = [ThemeDecorator(Theme.DARK)];
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is the simplest and most effective method to replace Storybook sidebar icons.

Create the file `manager-head.html` in your `.storybook` folder. This file lets you apply custom js, css, whatsoever to the application.

manager-head.html:

```html
<style>
button[data-nodetype="component"] svg,
[data-nodetype="component"] button svg {
   display: none!important;
}

button[data-nodetype="component"]::before,
button[data-nodetype="component"] button::before {
    content: '';
    width: 17px; /* set an icon size */
    aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
    background-image: url(your-icon.svg);
    background-size: cover;
}
</style>
```

The two selectors are to cover both cases when the sidebar item is standing alone and when it's wrapped in another element.

- `button[data-nodetype="component"]` for component icons
- `a[data-nodetype="document"]` for docs icons
- `a[data-nodetype="story"]` for story icons

My solution works for Storybook 7.1.1, i haven't tested it anywhere else